# I have an abstract algebra proof I am a little iffy on. Help please!

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I was independently studying abstract algebra and found the following problem:

The problem says to show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{7}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7})$.

The solution given was as follows:

[image]

Everything made since except line 4. Where does the $-3(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3})$ come from and why does it equal $4\sqrt{3}$?

Would someone be able to show be how this works for any case? In other words,

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})$ where $gcd(a,b) = 1$.

I wanted to use a similar argument as the above proof.

Comment: There's a misprint: it should be $(3\sqrt{7}+7\sqrt{3})-3(\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{3})=4\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that was the case, but was unsure!

Comment: One more question. In the second to last line, where does the $\frac{1}{4}$ come from?

Comment: The $1/4$ is used to remove the $4$; since it's rational, you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

$(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})^2 = a + b + 2\sqrt{ab} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}) \Rightarrow \sqrt{ab} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$.

Then, $\sqrt{ab}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}) = a\sqrt{b} + b\sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$

$\Rightarrow a\sqrt{b} + b\sqrt{a} - a(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}) = b\sqrt{a}-a\sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7})$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle\frac{1}{b-a} \cdot \sqrt{a}(b-a) = \sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})$

Since $\sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}), \sqrt{b} = (\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}) - \sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})$.

Comment: Yep! (except you forgot to do a replacement in line 3)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean it still has a 3 and a 7...

Comment: Ohhh I see. Thanks!

Comment: This is good; can you see that you need nothing else than $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$? Actually your proof uses $a\ne b$, but in this case the assertion is obvious. A good exercise, now, is finding out what conditions are needed so that $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There are some trivial cases, when one of $a$ or $b$ is square. Otherwise, $\sqrt{ab}\notin\mathbb Q$ (why?). Then try mimicking the proof verbatim.

Comment: Okay let me try that and then I will show you to see what you think.

Comment: I posted an answer. How does it look?

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb Q(\sqrt3+\sqrt7)$is a sub field of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt3,\sqrt7)$. The degree of the former must divide that of the later, which is clearly 4. The degree of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt3+\sqrt7)$ is greater than two, so must be 4, so the two fields are the same.